# Hive Editor - Not working in HUE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, mapr

When running the Hive query in Hive editor - I am getting the Timed out error, but the query running fine in Command Line Interface.

Also the HUE home -
potential misconfiguration detected. 
Hive Editor The application won't work without a running HiveServer 2.

All the hive services are running.

Comment: You must set the hive configurations under `beeswax` section in `hue.ini`

Comment: @franklinsijo it's configured in hue.ini!! all of a sudden it went off!

Comment: If it was a working setup, try restarting the Hive services and Hue supervisor.

Comment: @ franklinsijo yep...it was working and now it is not! i have restarted all the services. but it's not helping. still Hive editor is down.

Comment: Check whether HiveServer2 is in `LISTEN` state, `netstat -ntpl | grep 10000`

Comment: @franklinsijo ip's are 0.0.0.0.0:10000 and all are zero's. and i forgot to mention that it's a MapR distro!

Comment: @franklinsijo now HiveServer 2 is down! and am trying to restart it but its keep on going down after some time interval.

Comment: @franklinsijo it works fine on the CLI! only on HUE am getting this error! Query timed out error ! but i dont't understand if HiveServer 2 is down,how the query is running on CLI without any error???

Comment: CLI does not require `hiveserver2` but Hue does.

Comment: @franklinsijo okies Thanks for the info! Now the alarm went down...HiveServer 2 is up and running but how do i up the Hive Editor in the HUE?

Comment: Restart `supervisor`, it should be sufficient.

Comment: @franklinsijo You meant to say Hue service!!? It's MapR distro, am not finding any HUE supervisor in MCS!

Comment: Try [this](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Starting+the+Hue+Webserver)

Comment: @franklinsijo i confirmed with this command lsof -i:8888! Hue Webserver is up and running ! But HiveServer2 is keep on failing ! It keeps on going Up and Down !!

Comment: @franklinsijo..i tried this commands for hive metastore and hive port, [mapr@***** mapr]$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 9083
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9083                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17879/java
[mapr@***** mapr]$ sudo netstat -ntpl | grep 10000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      12639/java, am getting all the ip's 0!!! what am missing here???

Comment: Is this a Pesudo Distributed Cluster?

Comment: @franklinsijo..Nope...its multi node cluster.